# Twitter click event not working

Tags: javascript, twitter

I want to trigger a click callback js function on "Tweet". My code is:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="https://twitter.com/share" data-via="josephjohnbless">Tweet</a>
<script>
    window.twttr = (function (d, s, id) {
        var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function (f) { t._e.push(f) } });
    }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
</script>
<script>
    twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
        twttr.events.bind('click', function (event) { alert('yes'); });
    });
</script>
```

There is a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined` for `twttr.ready()`. I saw this to be a valid solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24698352/1972266, but, as I said, it is not working for me.

EDIT:
I solved my problem this way: 1. I changed this code:

```
<script>
    window.twttr = (function (d, s, id) {
        var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function (f) { t._e.push(f) } });
    }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
</script>
```

with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

2. I was calling this code:

   twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
           twttr.events.bind('click', function (event) { alert('yes'); });
       });

on the wrong place in my files. I was calling it on the parent view(my application is ASP.NET MVC) instead in the partial view, where i had my `<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="https://twitter.com/share" data-via="josephjohnbless">Tweet</a>` and `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>`. And that was it.

Comment: did you figure this out? it's not working for me either